# Select inside of textbox on mouse down

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically what I want to do is if the use hits mouse down inside of a div select the last cursor point inside of a textbox this way the user could still drag the mouse over the text to select it.

Currently I have this:

HTML:

```
<div class="VS-search-inner" onclick="innerSearchPanelClicked(event)">
```

JS:

```
function innerSearchPanelClicked(e){

  var inputToFocus = $( e.target ).find("input").last();
  if(inputToFocus.is('input')){
      inputToFocus.focus();
      var length = inputToFocus.val().length;
      inputToFocus.setCursorPosition(length);
  }
}
```

This works well on click but if I try to change it to mouse down it keeps loosing focus on the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse click is going through after the input is selected, causing it to lose focus. Try using a timeout.

```
function innerSearchPanelClicked(e){
  var target = e.target;
  setTimeout(function () {
    var inputToFocus = $( target ).find("input").last();
    if(inputToFocus.is('input')){
      inputToFocus.focus();
      var length = inputToFocus.val().length;
      inputToFocus.setCursorPosition(length);
    }
  },10);
}
```

Comment: It actually seems to work fine with mouse click and on mouse down it loses focus before I even let the the mouse up.

Comment: Did you try it with a timeout?

Comment: I apologize you where right. I thought mouse click meant the mouse had to go down and up this worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: For the record I could actually only get this working for Chrome.